# When I use UIGETFILE function then my gui minimize. How can I stop this to do this?

Tags: matlab

How can I remain open the GUI?

How can I fix this problem kindly help?

`[filename,filepath]=uigetfile({'*.bmp'},'Select and image');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem, you can see some previous solutions here:

- https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/296305-appdesigner-window-ends-up-in-background-after-uigetfile
- https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/317676-uigetfile-will-make-app-be-behind-another-windows
- https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/92bh7e/force_uigetfile_to_open_dialogue_in_front_of/

The solutions typically involve toggling the visibility of the GUI.